# MS Access - Division by zero + Nz()

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two cross tab queries (see below for structure). Pretty simple. The first takes the total of each building type that my company owns in each city, and the second takes the total of ALL (not just company owned) buildings by type in the entire city.

All I want to do is calculate a percentage, but I am having a lot of trouble. I think I am pretty close though, but for some reason, my `Nz()` function isn't working properly. I keep getting the "Division by zero error." Here's my percent formula:

```
DCount(
  "[ID]","[Company_owned]") / DCount(
    "[ID]","[City_Totals]", "[Year_built]=2000" & Nz(Year_built, "null")
  )
)
```

Here is the layout of my cross tab queries.

1)

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║               Building type:          1     2     3     4      5      6     7 ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║     City      Atlanta                 0     7     0     2      3      4     9 ║
║               New York                0     0     2     5      7      8     2 ║
║               San Francisco           1     1     2     3      4      5     6 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

2)

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║               Building type:          1     2     3     4      5      6     7 ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║     City      Atlanta                 8     9     3     2      3      7     9 ║
║               New York                0     0     2     7      7      9     2 ║
║               San Francisco           3     1     9     3      5      5     8 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting the "Division by zero" error and whether or not this is a sound strategy for calculating the percentages from data in two cross tab queries (I have also considered doing all of the percentage calculations in the report, but this seems a little more tedious)

Comment: You can use this http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to format tables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit here, but I think what you are looking for is something more like this:

```
DCount("[ID]","[Company_owned]") / _
DCount("[ID]","[City_Totals]", "[Year_built]" & _
  IIf(IsNull(Year_built), " Is Null", "=" & Year_built))
```

*Note: Leave off the line continuation chars (`_`) and just run each line together if you are doing this in a query.*

I think the reason you are having trouble is because the second criteria you wrote was evaluating to something like this: `[Year_built]=20002008` or this `[Year_built]=2000null`.

Even if leaving the `2000` in was just a typo in your question, this: `[Year_built]=null` would still not do what you seem to expect.  You need the `Is Null` statement in that case.